# How to get the Google search history of myself

Tags: google-search

Can I get my Google search history starting from the moment I started using the Google search engine?

Comment: You can get this information only if you were logged in with your Google Account while you searched.

Answer (score 1):

This is the page you are looking for: http://www.google.com/searchhistory/

Of course it only has data from when you were logged in to Google with your Google Account.